# C++: myfile.open ("example.txt") line: file not found?

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm learning about Input/Output with files in C++. I can compile my file, receive no error, but the file execution does not provide the result I expect.
I have looked on internet for an answer, but could not find it.

This is the C++ code:

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

I have created an empty "example.txt" file in which it can write. But I believe that the algorithm does not find that file on my computer though. Is that the problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: That works fine for me... Maybe the location is write-protected?

Comment: How are you running the program, and where is the file? IDEs like Visual Studio don't run the program with the working directory being the executable's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm will create file in directory where your executive file exactly is. If it doesn't exist - ofstream will create a new one. If you want to write to particular file, you should pass the absolute file path to ofstream.open, e.g. myfile.open("C:\temp\example.txt");

Comment: Thank you Evgeny. I see now that this file was created in the location of the exe file. But I also tried to specify the file path of the .txt I made, but received warnings. In line 7 I put: 'myfile.open ("C:\Users\E\Docs\T\F\Algo\example.txt");' example message after compilation: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\D' [enabled by default]| Why is that?

Comment: must  be "C:\\temp\\example.txt"

Comment: If you want to put '\' character in your string, you should use escape-symbol '\\', because '\' is reserved character for escape symbols such as '\n', '\t'. Correct: `myfile.open ("C:\\Users\\E\\Docs\\T\\F\\Algo\\example.txt");`

Answer (score 1):

```
myfile.open ("example.txt");
```

If there is not such a file, it will create a new file. So, the problem is not searching for an existing file.

Maybe your program hasn't the permission to create a file.